Find the line $y = k \quad (0 < k < 1)$, area between the two curves $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) = x^2$
The question goes as follows. I don't know how to use LaTeX, so I will get help from GPT. The topic is integration.

So, say we have
$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x) = x^2.$$
Find the line
$$ y = k \qquad (0 < k < 1) $$
that divides the region $R$ into two regions, denoted by $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$.

Here is my thought process
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} - x^2 \, \mathrm dx. 
$$
Therefore, calculating the integral from $[0,1]$, the area would turn out to be
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} - x^2 , \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{3},
$$
so I can already tell that that Region $\text{A}$ would be
$$
\frac{A_{\text{total}}}{2} = A_{\text{Region A}} = \frac{1}{6}.$$
However, this is where to solve for $k$, in which $k$ is horizontal between $[0,1]$ on $y$-axis.
That means
$$\int_{0}^{k} \sqrt{x} - x^2 \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{6}.$$
So, then, this is where I am stuck because, when plugging $k$ in, we get
$$\frac{2}{3}k^{\tfrac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}k^{3}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
However, this isn't computable and will give me a bogus answer. Isn't there another way to calculate it? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Substitute $k^{3/2} = u$ ...

Is the area of region $A$=that of region $B$? You haven't mentioned it explicitly.

For the area bounded by $y=\sqrt x$, $y=x^2$ and $y=k\in[0,1]$, you should integrate in terms of $y$ and not $x$.

@MathGuy: You are right, but it does not matter here because the region is symmetric  to the line $y=x$.

@MartinR yes, you are correct, I was saying that because the OP directly integrated from $x=0$ to $x=k$, which is conceptually incorrect, so I thought it'd be good to remind them of the correct way of integrating to find area.

@MathGuy well my thought process was to already assume that region A=B, I just dont know where to go from here, It's probably easier to integrate in terms of y. hence why I just went from x=0 and x=k assuming they are the same result for region B

also yes i am new to this forum so I am lost sorry will fix

Re-read the very first comment, which is by Martin R.  It facilitates your reducing the problem to solving a quadratic equation.  However, this assumes that the following equation is accurate:  $$\frac{2}{3}k^{\tfrac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{3}k^{3}=\frac{1}{6}.$$  I have not verified this equation.
